# Update Magento 2 PHP Settings - two php configuration? find right php.ini

Tags: magento-2.1, php-5.4

I would like to update **Magento 2** from **2.1.3 to 2.1.4**.
While readiness check I get this error and hint:

> PHP Settings Check *
>
> Your current PHP memory limit is 256M. Magento 2 requires it to be set
>   to 756M or more. As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini
>   file to increase memory_limit. (The command php --ini tells you where
>   it is located.) After that, restart your web server and try again.
>
> *In some cases, you might have two PHP configuration files: one for the PHP command line and for the web server. If so, make the change in
>   both php.ini files. For details, see the php.ini reference.

When I look at the phpinfo info page it’s correct:

> memory_limit  768M

with php —ini I get this path’s:

```
[~/www/magento]# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/alt/php56/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/alt/php56/etc/php-cli.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/alt/php56/link/conf
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/alt/php56/link/conf/alt_php.ini
```

PHP.ini file for php-cli

```
[~/www/magento]# php -i |grep php\.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/alt/php56/etc
Additional .ini files parsed => /opt/alt/php56/link/conf/alt_php.ini
```

in php.info i get this path’s

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /opt/alt/php56/etc
Loaded Configuration File   /opt/alt/php56/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files :/home/xxx/etc/php_settings/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /opt/alt/php56/link/conf/alt_php.ini, /home/xxx/etc/php_settings/conf.d/00-mycyon.ini
```

It is  not my  own webserver, so I can only edit this file:

```
/home/xxx/etc/php_settings/conf.d/00-mycyon.ini
```

The hosting provider says the `00-mycyon.ini` file overwrite the others.

But I get still the same error.

How can I find the right php.ini file which magento use?
Or is it possible to say magento that it take this php.ini file:
/home/xxx/etc/php_settings/conf.d/00-mycyon.ini

Thanks for every hint or idea!

Comment: I know, thats not the answer, but consider upgrading to PHP7. This MIGHT solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  I already tried to update but than i have the same problem. Phpinfo shows php Version 7 but Magento still show Version 5.6. I think the problem is that they use different php.ini files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Maybe it is also helpful for someone else.

I found this info: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/152908661755/your-current-php-memory-limit-is-128m-and-other

The problem is that the Readiness Check is dependent on the Cronjob.

The cronjob was displayed to me as correct, but it pointed to another php version than I thought.

So I changed it from:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/pitecch/public_html/magento/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >>
```

to

```
php -c /home/xxx/etc/php_settings/conf.d/00-mycyon.ini /home/pitecch/public_html/magento/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >>
```